# How to map a denormalized table to two entities?

Tags: hibernate, jpa, orm, hibernate-mapping

I have a denormalized database table containing employees and the department they work in:

```
EmployeeId EmployeeName DepartmentId DepartmentName
 1            Bob          1              HR
 2            Lisa         1              HR
 ...
```

`DepartmentId` and `EmployeeId` are the compound primary key. I cannot change the database. I would like to map this to two entities:

```
@Entity
@Data
class Employee {
   @Id
   @Column("employeeId")
   private int id;
   
   @Column("employeeName")
   private String name;

   @ManyToOne
   private Department department;
}

@Entity
@Data
class Department {
   @Id
   @Column("departmentId")
   private int id;
   
   @Column("departmentName")
   private String name;
}
```

But this doesn't work. How can I account for this impedance mismatch between my logic (object) model and database (physical) model? I've seen an [hierarchical](https://vladmihalcea.com/map-multiple-jpa-entities-one-table-hibernate/) approach to solving this but I don't believe that applies to my scenario since Employee and Department don't have any hierarchical relationship.

Answer (score 0):

One row can only represent one `Entity` Object. Any demoralised attributes that are repeated together can be treated as a `Value` object. `Value` object's lifecycle depends the lifecycle of the entity object. When the entity object gets deleted, the value object goes with it as well.

Even in hierarchical approach, each row can present a different `type` of book, but one row represents one entity only.

So you cannot represent them as two entities.